# Navigation bar - positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, navigation

I am having a heck of a time trying to get my navigation bar to stay put on all screen sizes/ browsers / etc...

I have tried :

```
header#top #logo {
   display: none!important;
}
#header-top, #header-space {
  display: none!important;
}

#header-outer {
 z-index: 10000!important;
}

#top nav > ol {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top:25%;
    left: 0px;

}
.nav {
    position:fixed;
    top:25%;
}
```

None of which seems to have a solid effect on the positioning, I have also tried position:left and played with all of the dimensional options, currently based on other suggestions (position:left) has locked it at the top of the page, though I would like the nav to sit underneath the header image and never, ever, for any reason move, not even one little pixel, i don't know if this is even possible, but any insight would be so much appreciated.

side note: if i can do this with just CSS, that would be outstanding

Comment: A fiddle producind this issue will be good to provide any help

Comment: Maybe some HTML code would be useful?

Comment: hey -- not sure if this is what you mean, but i've put it into the fiddle, though i am very unfamiliar with it! My apologies if this is not what you meant  -- https://jsfiddle.net/1q0mq83w/ @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: @geek1011 it very well might be! i'm a level 1000 noob and going through this all very blindly so i'm sure there are major important elements i am missing -- i just, as you might imagine, have no idea what to do with them or how to go about finding information that is not outrageously conflicting haha 

Thank you both for your responses

Comment: @jmf Can you add your HTML code to the fiddle?

Comment: i, filled with embarrassment and regret, do not know exactly where to find that ... i'm imagining it would be within the header.php ? Currently on the hunt! @geek1011

Comment: @jmf Yes, it would be there

Comment: @geek1011 --- taking a gander in there, though i'm kind of unclear as to which portion i'm looking for, I'm working primarily out of a child theme so i'm currently searching through the actual Salient theme which is a rather hefty file, I have searched for anything related to navigation, came up with one match, 

one :wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'top_nav', 'menu' => 'Top Navigation Menu', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) ); 

and when i search just nav" I come up with 24 results, and i'm so sorry i'm not currently cool enough to create a chat! and im out of characters

Comment: @jmf Can you open the page in a web browser, and paste the source code the web browser gives you into a pastebin and post a link?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/t2EZYg5R I hope this is correct!

Thank you to the moon and back for your help thus far, you're probably the most responsive person i've encountered, thank you so much @geek1011


---- sorry, if it helps http://trillium.in-development.ca is the page in question

Comment: side note:

#top nav > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top:315px;
    left: 15%;

}


allowed me to bring it down to the posion i wanted but wouldnt fix it's position on scroll, and now is apparently useless haha @geek1011

Comment: @jmf I'll have a look at it

Comment: I so much appreciate it, thank you endlessly for your time, you're a good human @geek1011

Comment: @jmf I am kind of stuck, but I think it might be easier to accomplish if the nav is a child of the header, then stick the header to the top. Also, some other cars might be interfering. Hope it helps.

Comment: @geek1011 no worries! I appreciate your help so much! I'll look further into making the nav a child and go from there! Endless appreciation, thanks a million! (also flip yeah onterrible!) Cheers :)

Comment: @geek1011 also, sorry, how on earth to i credit you for your answer/time? over the moon appreciative of your time spent

Comment: @jmf Tell me if you need any more help or if you get it working, and there is no need to thank me.

Comment: hey @geek1011, i appreciate therefore i thank profusely haha, i guess i'm kind of stuck on where to modify the header.php -- I've read things with regards to moving a chunk of header.php below another chunk but the salient theme seems to refer to certain elements differently. Still reading away though, the answer must exist somewhere haha

Comment: @geek1011 thank you!

Comment: @geek1011  
 #header-top, #header-space {
  display: none!important;
}

seemed to do the trick! a little glitchy but it's staying put :) (i can take no credit for finding this haha, but if you're in the realm of ever needing this....)